# jquery syntax selector - contains

Tags: jquery

I pass a function an xml variable: `node`.

```
function (node){
    //how do I do this part:
    $(node + ":contains('some_random_text')");
}
```

I want to find a sub node that has the random text.

Comment: What are you trying to pass as the `node` as does that not work?

Comment: I think you should have a look at this link http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would have to do is pass in the xml as the `context` to what you are looking for:

```
var _xml = "these are xml nodes";

function (node){
    //how do I do this part:
    $(node + ":contains('some_random_text')", _xml);
}
```

Otherwise it is looking for the match in your document;

Comment: yes, that's what was happening, I was getting document information.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your selector to this:

```
var contElem = $(":contains('some_random_text')", node);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$(node).find( ":contains('some_random_text')" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function (node){
 $(node).find(":contains('some_random_text')").each(function ()
    {
      ...
    });


    }
```